# Chrome extensions - runtime.onStartup before any other actions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

persistent = false in the 'background' section of the manifest means, that background page can be unloaded from memory and launched again later.

I have a variable, which i need to save across loading and unloading of the background page and browser. I'm ok with this, I can use localStorage or chrome.storage.sync/local.

But i need to change this variable when a browser is started. And I need to do it before any other actions.

So, my code is:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("variable", 0);
});
//main actions:
var my_var = localStorage.getItem("variable");
my_var += 3;
localStorage.setItem("variable", my_var);
```

I need to run chrome.runtime.onStartup before the main actions, but I can't because the chrome.runtime.onStartup event can fire after main actions.

Main actions will run every time when background page will be loaded into memory, because of persistent = false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API to set an immediately executed alarm; its callback will be queued right after the `onStartup`:

- event.js:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
      console.log("startup");
      localStorage.variable = 0;
  });

  chrome.alarms.create("main", {when: Date.now()});
  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
      console.log("execute");
      if (alarm.name == "main") {
          mainCode();
      }
  });

  function mainCode() {
      ...................
      ...................
  }
  ```
- manifest.json:

  ```
  "permissions": ["alarms"],
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I'm still a little confused, and correct me if I'm wrong: You have to run sync functions after starting, then I think you need to make the following change:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {

    //chrome.runtime.onStartup finished

    //disable
    //localStorage.setItem("variable", 0);

    //main actions:
    var my_var = localStorage.getItem("variable");
    my_var += 3;
    localStorage.setItem("variable", my_var);
});
```

Start the `chrome.runtime.onStartup` before any other code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use code you wrote. Because I need to perform the main actions every time when background page loads into memory (as I said, persistent is false).

Comment: And I need to run localStorage.setItem("variable", 0) just once, when browser starts and THEN do the main actions.

Comment: You could post more parts of the code, it is still a little confused trying to help